# android: how to use FragmentStatePagerAdapter easy way?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, viewpage

I'm looking for any tutorial or sample code that describe how to using the `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best tutorial is the example `Fragment -> State Pager` in the `Support v4 Demos` application available in the SDK directory `extras -> android -> support -> samples -> Support4Demos`

Good luck!!

Comment: thanks :) .. BTW there is a lot of useful samples

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html